# Eclipse Mars wont start after Java 8 Update 71

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed the Java 8 Update 71 yesterday and now my Eclipse did not start after that. Windows only shows a short loading symbol on the mouse and that was it. Before I had the Java 8 Update 66 and everything worked fine.

So I tried to open it with the `-clean` parameter and set the path variable. Removed Eclipse and the whole `workspace` folder, but this didn't solved the problem. Then I uninstalled the java package in the windows software panel and the only one what is left right now, is the `Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 66`. Then I tried to start Eclipse and it works! But I don't understand why, because the Path Variable was set to the newer J8u71 `/bin` folder.

Now I am wondering, should I try to install the SDK 8u71 again or is this not needed? Since Oracle says it fix some security issues...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-install `SDK 8u71` and then edit your `eclipse.ini` file located in same folder as the executable.

Change the value of the `-vm` parameter to the path of the new Java version.

For example

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin
```

Comment: @user3772108 I have no idea, but I had the same problem and that's how I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. But I don't understand why the update changed something on the old SDK or the way how Eclipse used it.

Comment: I just tried a restart and now it is working even without the `-vm` value. Then I saw it still uses u66. I closed eclipse and changed the `eclipse.ini`. But it still uses jdk1.8.0_66?

Comment: But the path is valid, I just tried to open the folder

Comment: @user3772108 Do you have a -vm parameter with the new version path in your eclipse.ini? It's unclear from your comments.

Comment: Yes, I have the parameter in the eclipse.ini now. But I was confusing the VM with the SDK. Where can I see the JVM eclipse is using?

Comment: Another thing I just saw, when I start a program eclipse uses the old SDK (u66), but I changed the PATH Environment value to the newest

Comment: This answer is correct, however I had to set the path to include the javaw.exe (C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin/javaw.exe) as pointed here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is below :

We have use openFile above -vm argument.

For example

Example 1 :
openFile 
-vm 
C:\program files\Java\jdk1.7\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Example 2 :
openFile
-vm 
C:\program files\Java\jdk1.7\bin\javaw.exe

See the attachment for reference.
[eclipse.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gox7c.png)